# Finding row that has shapefile containing lat/long point in PostGIS geometry column

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude, point-in-polygon

I am fairly new to PostGIS and I'm trying to return a row in my table that has the shapefile containing a lat/long point I pass in via st_contains. Below is a query I wrote myself that brings back 0 rows with no errors as seen below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM es_zones 
WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.952545 40.774576)'))=true;
```

Having found a query similar of that to which I am trying to accomplish [here](http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/point-in-polygon-in-postgis/), below is my last query ran.

```
SELECT * 
FROM es_zones 
WHERE ST_Contains(es_zones.geom,ST_transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-73.952545 40.774576)',26918),26918))=true 
AND ST_Distance(es_zones.geom,ST_transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-73.952545 40.774576)',21918),21918))=false;
```

which also brings back 0 rows as seen below

```
----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----+----------+-------+--------

gid | schooldist | boro | initials | creat_date | edit_date | zoned_dist | boro_num | shape_leng | shape_area | remarks | dbn | esid_no | label | geom 

(0 rows)
```

Really not sure where I am going wrong.

I was able to get QGIS set up and connected to my PostGIS data. I don't understand what the 997487, 221261 coordinates are.

How do they correspond to the lat/lon points I got back from my GeoCoder Gem?

I passed them in as my point but got the following error;

> ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries

[image: QGIS view of PostGIS data]

Verifying the SRID shows

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM es_zones LIMIT 1;
 st_srid 
---------
  926918
 (1 row)
```

So it sounds like something may have happened to my spacial_ref_sys table, or perhaps I didn't get it configured correctly to begin with. A Google search for my last error `ERROR:  GetProj4StringSPI: Cannot find SRID (4326) in spatial_ref_sys` returned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031811/how-do-i-fix-missing-postgis-srids-in-postgresql) StackOverflow question. Which points to running `spatial_ref_sys.sql` to regenerate the rows in that table.

I found some elaboration on how to go about executing `spatial_ref_sys.sql` in the PostGIS documentation [here](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch02.html#id2754935), but I'm confused why it says it can't find SRID 4326 when looking in PGAdmin I can see it as shown below!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. If you were hoping to get something in Manhattan, your WKT is incorrect - you're asking for Antarctica. Try putting the longitude first, then the latitude) - its an X-Y thing.

Comment: @BradHards thanks for clarifying. I made those changes in both instances and added ST_ to my GeometryFromText and Transform methods. Both were getting flagged. Still getting empty return from both though `=# SELECT * FROM es_zones WHERE ST_Contains(es_zones.geom,ST_transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(73.952545 40.774576)',26918),26918))=true;` `=# SELECT * FROM es_zones WHERE ST_Contains(es_zones.geom,ST_transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(73.952545 40.774576)',26918),26918))=true and ST_Distance(es_zones.geom,ST_transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(73952545 40.774576)',21918),21918))=0.00;`

Comment: Please edit the question (just click edit below the question) rather than posting comments. The syntax at the top of your original question looks OK (a bit strange, but not wrong). Hint: you probably want a negative longitude, and probably a decimal place.

Comment: I had tried the longitude previously as both a negative and positive value. The Ruby gem Geocoder gives it back to me as a negative in degrees decimal. A quick Google search shows it as a positive value.

Comment: Are you sure the data is in WGS84 longitude/latitude? What does SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM es_zones LIMIT 1; show? What does SELECT As_EWKT(geom) FROM es_zones LIMIT 1; show?

Comment: @BradHards the SRID showed 926918 which is what I had to enter using the PostGIS extension shape file uploader as the SRID for it to complete the upload. The As_EWKT came back as no function matching the given name and argument types.

Comment: Sorry, ST_AsEWKT: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html, although that SRID looks badly broken - did you mean 26918? Where did the data come from? Why did you choose that SRID to upload as? Also which are you using 21918 as the source SRID, and 26918 in QGIS?

Comment: I downloaded the data from([NYC Open Data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Education/2013-2014-School-Zones/pp5b-95kq)) as a shapefile. I referenced a [tutorial](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/loading_data.html) that was working with nyc subway data. They were using SRID 26918. The PostGIS shapefile uploader kept giving me an error with that srid. I later found the SRID [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26918/postgis/) with a 9 in front of the 5 digit number (926918). PostGIS shapefile uploader accepted that as the SRID and uploaded my shapefiles.

Answer (score 3):

The input data is in EPSG 26918 ([UTM zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) 18N). So if you want to query against that, you need to use that spatial reference system. If you want to ask in longitude / latitude, you need to transform that into 26918, which is easy to do with [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html).

The conversion looks like:

```
SELECT ST_Transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-73.952545 40.774576)',4326), 26918)
```

So if you want to find any area that contains that particular point:

```
SELECT * FROM es_zones WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_Transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-73.952545 40.774576)',4326), 26918))
```

Comment: This is very close to the query I started with, except maybe with the lat lon switched. This returns ERROR:  GetProj4StringSPI: Cannot find SRID (4326) in spatial_ref_sys. I have the return from ST_AsEWKT. It starts with SRID=926918;MULTIPOLYGON((( with a long array of two point numbers of the format xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx,....)))

Comment: What does SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid=4326; show? Do you have a database cleaner? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031811/how-do-i-fix-missing-postgis-srids-in-postgresql might be helpful.

Comment: SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid=4326 returns;  srid | auth_name | auth_srid | srtext | proj4text 
------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------
(0 rows) I don't have a database cleaner. But I had seen the Stackoverflow question you posted above. It is what lead me to check the spatial_ref_sys table via the pgAdmin tool

Comment: It makes no sense for SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid=4326 to return no rows but for there to be equivalent rows in PGAdmin. I have no idea what sort of problem could have caused that though - are you confident that your whole postgis setup is correct?

Comment: This is my first time working with GIS data and setting up the PostGIS extension. At this point there is very little I am completely confident in. However as I posted, and you have noted, there it is in PGAdmin.

Comment: have you installed postgis extension properly? CREATE EXTENSION postgis; in your database

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at your dataset visually (you could connect to your database using QGIS for example). That way you can check if a point would actually be in the polygon, and as @BradHards suggests, check that you have the correct lon/lat when constructing the geometry.

Your query looks fine - it's not necessary to have `true` at the end. You can just do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM es_zones 
WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon lat)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  ST_X(point) AS longitude, ST_Y(point) AS latitude 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT 
    ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) AS point 
  FROM 
    "28DSE250GC_SIR" 
  LIMIT 
    1
) AS subquery
```

Comment: "28DSE250GC_SIR" is your table name

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, please add more details as explanation.